# Is there any equivalent to System.ComponentModel.Composition library in .Net Standard?

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

.Net has System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll for MEF. Is there any equivalent library present in .Net Standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [.net standard 2.0](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.ComponentModel.Composition) you need to use this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Composition):

> This namespace provides classes that constitute the core of the
>   Managed Extensibility Framework, or MEF.
>
> **Commonly Used Types:**
>
> ```
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionContractMismatchException
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionError
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportAttribute
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportAttribute
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ApplicationCatalog
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartException
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ExportDefinition
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ReflectionModelServices
> ```